# WSS 3.0 on SBS 2003 Search Not Working

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0, windows-sbs-2003

I've got WSS 3.0 installed on SBS 2003 (side-by-side install with SBS's WSS 2.0).  Everything works fine but search.

- I get no errors or warnings in the event log.
- I've got all the WSS services running under domain accounts (e.g. not network service)
- NTLM auth is being used.

When I try to search, I get a basic "No results matching your search were found" page.

I've been banging my head on this one for days and I've just about lost hope.  Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I did quite a bit to try and get this working, and finally did.

The very last thing I did was to disable the loopback check introduced in 2003 SP1.  Searches started working.  Since this check is a security enhancement, I re-enabled it, and then added the fully qualified hostname of the Sharepoint site to the list of names mapped to the loopback address, as [documented here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;896861). Restarted IIS Admin and search is working fine.